# Why $c(a_1 a_2 ... a_k)c^{-1}$ is the k-cycle $(c(a_1) c(a_2)... c(a_3))$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

If $a,b,c \in S_n$, why $c(a_1 a_2 ... a_k)c^{-1}$ is the k-cycle $(c(a_1) c(a_2)... c(a_3))$?

(I need this to prove that two permutations are conjugate iff they have the same cyclic structure.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have
 $$(a_1\,a_2\,\dots\,a_k)\,(a_i)\ =\ a_{i+1}$$
for $i=1,2,\dots,k$ and $a_{k+1}:=a_1$.

Now, check what the given permutation $\ c\,(a_1\,a_2\,\dots\,a_k)\,c^{-1}\ $ does to the elements $c(a_i)$. 
Finally, check that no other elements are moved.